# Aurelia custom modal component

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, aurelia, bootbox

I'm using [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com) but since now I want to use a very custom modal dialog (change HTML markup on the modal etc) I was thinking on using a custom component.

I've created custom components before, but I've always included them on my view (HTML) side.

What I want to achieve is the same behavior of bootbox.js (fire the modal from my JS side) but on my own component, something like:

```
my_custom_modal.alert(message, callback)
my_custom_modal.prompt(message, callback)
```

What would it be the best way to achieve this?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you looked into the aurelia-dialog plugin? http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/dialog#introduction

Comment: If you are interested in creating your own, here is a great blog post discussing how: http://davismj.me/blog/easy-dialog/

Comment: thanks @peinearydevelopment it looks good. but I was looking to do something just like bootbox, which I only need to include on my JS file and call it from there. without any need to require anything on the HTML view.